# COUNT(Col1) by partitioning Col2 values in equidistant intervals

Tags: mysql, count, range, partitioning, intervals

MySQL

I have two columns. Col1 contains a list of IDs, Col2 contains a list of numbers (ranging between -100 and 200+). I want the COUNT(IDs) WHERE Col2 BETWEEN -100 AND -75, going all the way to the upper limit in intervals of 25.

What is the most efficient way of doing this using MySQL (or Excel). Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. You say you want values between -100 and -95 (which are -100,-99,-98,-97,-96,-95) in intervals of 25 (none exist) up to the limit of 200 (which is well outside your specified range)

Comment: I want COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 BETWEEN -100 AND -75, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 BETWEEN -75 AND -50, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 BETWEEN -50 AND -25, ...., 50 AND 75, ..... 150 AND 175, ....

Comment: In my question, I actually meant to say "...WHERE Col2 BETWEEN -100 AND -75..." and not '-95' - my error, hence, the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 BETWEEN -100 AND -75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Interval1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 BETWEEN -74 AND -50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Interval2,
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 BETWEEN 176 AND 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Interval12
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
select count(Col1) cnt
from ta
group by ceil(col2 / 25);
```

Think, it'll be shorter =)

Comment: This is definitely much shorter and effective, though rounding up using the CEIL wouldn't work for what I want to output. Col2 contains a list of random +ve, -ve numbers, they are NOT equidistant. for example, I'd have atleast 180 different numbers for a set of 200 records. To partition Col2 by interval, I have to use a series of conditions using the BETWEEN operator.

Comment: @doubleu4: Rounding up or down is up to your choice (don't use `CEIL()` if you want something slightly different). But this answer is definitely working. What exactly do you want to output?

Comment: @ypercube This wouldn't work for what I want, for example, consider this piece of series in Col2: "...-75, -72, -65, -22, -18,...". Using the CEIL(), I wouldn't know COUNT(Col1) = ?? WHERE Col2 BETWEEN -50 AND -25. To be precise, in terms of the data I processed, I wanted (got) 42 data points, the CEIL query gave me over 80.

Comment: sure, but this is a very neat technique.